# How to set line width and color when plotting a shapefile with plot()

Tags: r, plot, maps, shapefile

I have a simple shapefile I want to plot with the general plot() (I noticed that ggplot is extremely slow in plotting maps).

I can correctly plot the shape with the code

```
library(maptools)    
map_shp <- readShapePoly(map_filepath)
map <- fortify(map_shp)
plot(map)
```

But how could I define the color and width of the lines?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you aren't set on using **ggplot2** for everything, you can sidestep `fortify()` and just use the **sp** package's well-developed tools for plotting objects of class `SpatialPolygons*`:

```
library(rgdal) # For readOGR(), generally preferable to readShapePoly() IMHO
library(spdep) # For the "columbus.shp" file that ships with the package

map <- readOGR(dsn = system.file("etc/shapes", package="spdep"), 
               layer = "columbus")
plot(map, border="red", lwd=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you suggest to use ggplot2 also for rendering maps? I noticed it is very slow.

Comment: @CptNemo -- I might not be the right person to comment, since I don't use **ggplot2**. I do use R for mapping and spatial analyses, and can tell you that the **sp**, **raster**, **rasterVis** packages have good support for base and **lattice** graphics. Also, I've heard your same complaint about **ggplot2** from others, followed by the recommendation that they use **lattice** or base graphics instead.